# Where does a large file go when I delete it from a volume?

Tags: finder, trash

I deleted several files around 1 GB or more from an external drive with `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. I cannot see them in `~/.Trash` and Finder refuses to go to `/Volumes/<volume name>/.Trash` by saying it does not exist, and it refuses to complete the location starting with `/Volumes/<volume name>/.Tr`.

Where did the files go?

Answer (score 2):

List the volume's hidden folders in the Terminal with:

```
$ ls -laht /Volumes/
...
d-wx-wx-wt    3 mmorin  staff   102B 12 Sep 09:35 .Trashes
...
```

The directory `.Trashes` is what you're looking for, which is why `.Trash` does not exist.

In my case, I needed `sudo` to view the directory, which explains why `/Volumes/<volume name>/.Tr` did not complete. Nested under the directory 501 are the deleted files:

```
$ sudo ls -lahtr ../.Trashes/501
total 15943672
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 _unknown  _unknown   1.0G  3 Jan  2018 some file.MP4
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 _unknown  _unknown   999M  3 Jan  2018 another file.MP4
...
```

Comment: Your user ID is _probably_ 501, but if you are not sure, you can run `id -u` to find out. You can also use `$UID` in most shells. So, if you want to go to the Trash folder in a given volume, use `cd "/Volumes/FOO/.Trashes/$UID/"` (and replace `FOO` with your volume name)

Comment: Yes, my user ID is 501.